# React Redux "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I'm pretty new to React and I created a simple game. I now decided to rebuild it and start using Redux. I use

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)} in `Main.js`
```

to pass props to first child which is World.js:

```
 Main.js
    (...)
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)} //props passed to World
    (...)
 export default Main;
```

then in World.js i pass props to Interface component:

```
World.js
   (...)
     <Interface
        {...this.props}
        /> 
   (...) 
export default World;
```

Finally, `Interface.js` is where the problem is. In `getCurrentLocation`function I'm trying to reach `locations` that is one of component props. It is available as prop to the component but in function it says  "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". The other thing is i had to change the sythax from

`getCurrentLocation = (event) => {...` to `getCurrentLocation  (event)  {...` in order it to work

```
Interface.js

class Interface extends React.Component {

    getCurrentLocation  (event)  { // Why is getCurrentLocation = (event) => ... not working?
      
        event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
        const locationName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
    
        const updatedLocation={
            ...this.props.locations[locationName], //Line with error: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
            isCurrentLocation: true,
        }
        (...)
         }
       };

render() {
 
return (
  (...)
)
```

Thanks to everyone interested.

Comment: Do you understand what the error message is telling you?

Comment: not quite, my thinking is: I can display location in return like return (<div> {this.props.locations.sampleLocation </div> ). It is in component, but why not in a function in this component since "this" refers to current component?. It used to work before using Redux

Comment: From my understanding, it is not receiving props as there is no constructor in which you are receiving. add super(props) inside your constructor.

Comment: @Przemek What it's telling you is that that `this`  is undefined. Solving your problem will involve investigating why that is the case. I don't think it has anyting to do with redux though. It's probably something to do how you've declared your class, and/or your babel config.

Comment: I suggest posting a small repro on Code Sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding construtor like this fixed the issue

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getCurrentLocation = this.getCurrentLocation.bind(this);
        this.setCurrentLocation = this.props.setCurrentLocation.bind(this);
      }
```